# Liking a facebook status using og_likes iOS functional error

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement "Liking a Status" into my application. I am using the Facebook SDK references and have come up with this bit of code :

```
- (void) likeAStatus : (NSString *) postId {
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://facebook.com/%@", postId];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        post, @"object",
                        nil
                        ];
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/og.likes"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          NSLog(@"Result is %@", result);
                          NSLog(@"Error is %@", error);

                          NSString *idFromCreate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]];

                          /* make the API call */
                          [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:idFromCreate
                                                       parameters:params
                                                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                completionHandler:^(
                                                                    FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                    id result,
                                                                    NSError *error
                                                                    ) {
                                                    NSLog(@"Result is %@", result);
                                                    NSLog(@"Error is %@", error);
                                                }];
                      }];
}
```

Now when I run this on a post that I haven't liked before (I am simply had coding the postID for now) I get this response in the console : (I was just printing the action ID to make sure it was parsing the response properly)

```
2014-01-13 15:59:43.766 Unifeed[5336:70b] Result is {
    id = 10151765515511916;
}
2014-01-13 15:59:43.767 Unifeed[5336:70b] Error is (null)
2014-01-13 15:59:43.767 Unifeed[5336:70b] The ID is /10151765515511916
2014-01-13 15:59:44.052 Unifeed[5336:70b] Result is {
    "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = true;
}
2014-01-13 15:59:44.053 Unifeed[5336:70b] Error is (null)
```

This is looking like it works, unfortunately when I go and check my Facebook and look at this specific post it is not liked.... If I check my activity log on Facebook I do not see that I liked this status.

Any ideas as to what is going on or any suggestions to a different method of liking a status update? Also is the "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = true a good thing?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out - it was a differentiation of the graph API call. Now the code looks like this :

```
- (void) likeAStatus : (NSString *) postId {
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes", postId];

/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath: post
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          NSLog(@"Result is %@", result);
                          NSLog(@"Error is %@", error);
                      }];
}
```

Hope this helps someone out in the future!!

Andy